# Print two area charts in one diagram without stacking them above each other?

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, svg, dimple.js

I want to print two area charts in one diagram using dimple.js. I did it like this:

```
var svg = dimple.newSvg("#chart", svgWidth, svgHeight);
var chart = new dimple.chart(svg, data);
var xAxis = chart.addCategoryAxis("x", "DayOfMonth");
xAxis.title = null;
xAxis.addOrderRule("Date");
var yAxis = chart.addMeasureAxis("y", "Amount");
yAxis.title = null;

var series = chart.addSeries("Type", dimple.plot.area);
series.interpolation = "cardinal";
chart.draw();
```

Here is a JSFiddle I created: http://jsfiddle.net/7LoLLkfp/1/

The problem is that the two charts are above each other. When you look at the last value for DayOfMonth 20. Views should be at 6 and Likes should be at 4. In my case likes are drawn at 6 + 4 = 10.

How can I correctly draw two area charts in one diagram without stacking them above each other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set series.stacked to false e.g.

```
var series = chart.addSeries("Type", dimple.plot.area);
series.interpolation = "cardinal";
series.stacked = false;
chart.draw();
```

If you want to change the order set an addOrderRule

```
series.addOrderRule(["Views", "Likes"]);
```

or

```
series.addOrderRule(["Likes", "Views"]);
```

Comment: Does not work as it should. How do I change the order of the charts. I mean change the order which chart is in front.

Comment: Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5bxbk39k/2/ Look at the last point the Views graph (blue) should be the highest but it is not.

Comment: Thanks that is awesome.

Comment: May be you have an idea on that? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32892402/how-to-interpolate-missing-values-in-my-chart

Answer (score -1):

I think the issue is using stacked area charts.  To display the area it will stack one on top of the other.  You are probably better using a different chart type such as line

Comment: I want to use two area charts.